# why it is giving me seg fault ? Vertical view of Binary tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

The given code is not accepted and giving me seg error.I have used map to store the vertical line values along with the tree node data on each line.

```
void getvorder(Node *root,map<int,vector<int>> &m,int hd)
 {
     
     //base case
     if(root==NULL)
     return;
     
     m[hd].push_back(root->data);
     
     getvorder(root,m,hd-1);
     getvorder(root,m,hd+1);
 }
```

// root: root node of the tree

```
vector<int> verticalOrder(Node *root)
{
    //Your code here
    vector<int> v;
    map<int,vector<int>>m;
    //initial hd=0;
    int hd=0;
    if(root==NULL) return v;
    getvorder(root,m,hd);
    //traverse the map and print each element
    map<int,vector<int>> :: iterator it;
    for(it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<it->second.size();i++)
        {
            v.push_back(it->second[i]);
        }
    }
 return v;
    
    
}
```

Comment: No traversal is happening. You're just checking the root over and over and over: `getvorder(root,m,hd-1);`.

Comment: The function `getvorder(root,m,hd-1);` is running infinitely. You get stuck in recursion never hitting the base case, resulting in crossing the allocated memory limit for function stack and you get segmentation fault.

Comment: @risingStark thanks buddy. I should have called root->left and root->right recursively.

Comment: @Welbog you are absolutely correct mate I should have called the left and right child recursively.

Comment: While adding a question, please consider that everyone may not be familiar with the concept of `Vertical view of Binary tree`. It might be helpful if you add the actual problem statement, or a supporting figure to illustrate what is meant by `Vertical view of Binary tree`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffc3eabcff8 (pc 0x0000002a08c3 bp 0x000000000040 sp 0x7ffc3eabd000 T0)
==31==ABORTING
```

Usually `stack-overflow` error in recursion indicate the recursion fall in infinite loop, meaning the recursive call never meet the base-case condition.

Now, if you check your code keeping in mind that there is a problem in the recursive call, might help finding the problem easily. Your recursively call to `getvorder()` is the source of the problem, as you repetitively calling this function with the `root` node and the recursive call will end when this `root` node become **null** (your base-case). Now, as you call the `getvorder()` function with the same node again and again, it produce the `stack-overflow` error.

The following code solves the problem:

```
void getvorder(Node *root,map<int,vector<int>> &m,int hd)
{
     //base case
     if(root==NULL) return;
     
     m[hd].push_back(root->data);
     
     getvorder(root->left, m, hd-1);
     getvorder(root->right, m, hd+1);
 }

// root: root node of the tree
vector<int> verticalOrder(Node *root)
{
    //Your code here
    vector<int> v;
    map<int,vector<int>>m;
    //initial hd=0;
    int hd=0;
    if(root==NULL) return v;
    getvorder(root,m,hd);
    //traverse the map and print each element
    map<int,vector<int>> :: iterator it;
    for(it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<it->second.size();i++)
        {
            v.push_back(it->second[i]);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```